# How to maintain imageview size and font size across the screen resolution including tablet

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I am new to android and trying to figure out how to set logo and font size across all the screen resolution. For XHDPI resolution my logo size is 60 dp and font size is 23sp. I know that MDPI resoultion is half of XHDPI resolution and XXHDPI resolution is double of what XHDPI resolution but these ratios are not working as per my expectation also i need to maintain same aspect ratio for tablet as well. Please help me out here

Answer (score 1):

1. Define the image sizes in dimensions.xml file.
2. Create a different dimensions.xml files for different resolutions. Ex;-

   values - dimen.xml
   values-sw600 - dimensions.xml
   values-sw720 - dimensions.xml

Comment: What should be ratio size in dimensions XML

Answer (score 0):

you can use the constraints layout (check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html))

or you can create different layouts depending on the screen size. ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html))

Comment: Creating different layout for different screen will take me ages to complete the project i have 32 screen of app to be completed. 32*5 is too large for the maintenance as well

Comment: so use the constraints layout, it's designed to fit the responsive designs.

Comment: Let me checkout this one and will comment then